Web scraping with Flutter
I'm trying to scrape a website using Flutter, the goal is to create an application that tracks trains from my city to Milan so I can use that instead of looking on the official apps which are awful. The issue is that when you start a new session on the website in question a banner to accept cookies appears, so when I try to send an http request to the url it returns me just the banner and not the entire html page like I want. I tried using "puppeteer" to automatically accept the cookies and then scrape the page but it only works on Flutter desktop. I tried many solution but I'm not really into web scraping, so I hope somebody could help me. The url I want to scrape is the following:
https://www.trenord.it/store/#/en/booking/step1?departure=MILANO%20PORTA%20GARIBALDI&destination=MILANO%20BOVISA%20POLITECNICO&from=20241211&fromstart=08:58

